# Create array colors similar to the selected color

Tags: java, android

Currently I generate random colors to paint, but I would like to know if there is a method to generate random colors within a range of the selected color, I want the colors not to be totally random, but to be from the same range of colors as the selected one

```
        int colorselected = colors.getFirstColor();
        int colorrandom = ((int) (Math.random() * 16777215));

        paint4.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(colorselected+colorrandom, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
```

Comment: So what ideas do you have about this? What defines a 'color range'? What other digital representations of color are there, besides an int?

Comment: One has to use the RGB components and on any of them do a limited random change,, the sum of the changes sufficiently diffferent.

Comment: I can get the RGB color and modify the parameters independently to get a similar color, the problem is that I don't know how to automatically modify the parameters for each selected color, I don't know how to obtain the necessary configuration for each color.
I have thought of an alternative and it is that when doing colorpicker modify the x and y axis to obtain similar colors, but I think it is not the best solution.